# PHP strip_tags() function

Tags: php

When was the strip_tags() function first introduced to PHP? Which version?

Comment: If you're considering using it, please [read this slightly biased comparison of HTML validation engines](http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison#striptags) first to understand the things it can't do correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was added on PHP 4.0 beta 2, Aug 9 1999. Information taken from [here](http://php.net/ChangeLog-4.php).

Comment: Given the PHP3 answer below and the wording of the changelog entry, and considering how PHP4 was built (effectively a rewrite of the underlying engine), chances are that the changelog entry is just documenting that the old function was modernized.

Answer (score 2):

PHP3 introduced strip_tags to the php language

Comment: http://www.bradino.com/php-functions/strip_tags/ php3 isn't documented on php.net btw

Comment: And ye I guess php3 doesn't really matter that much and it isn't written on php.net since they removed the old stuff (which makes sense) just thought I'd do some deeper research :) actually it was php3.0.8 according to sources

Comment: +1 for being correct - it's in the PHP v3 manual (http://medialab.freaknet.org/php3/function.strip-tags.html) and, as Alex says, the published php.net manual no longer includes v3

Answer (score 0):

Check the strip_tags page:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

You can see the earliest comment was in 2001.